# trying to understand one js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
!function($, window, document, _undefined)
{
    XenForo.PrefixManager = function($select)
    {
        function update()
        {
            $checkboxes.each(function()
            {
                var $option = $select.find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').attr('disabled', !this.checked);

                if (!this.checked && $option.is(':selected'))
                {
                    $select.find('option').first().attr('selected', true);
                }
            });
        }

        var $checkboxes = $($select.data('checkboxes')).click(update);

        update();
    };

    // *********************************************************************

    XenForo.register('select.PrefixManager', 'XenForo.PrefixManager');

}
(jQuery, this, document);
```

Question:

why we put these parameters(window, document, _undefined)? in function body, we did not use them.

Comment: You use jQuery here: `$($select.data('checkboxes')).click(update);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a way to protect these variables names from overridden by other scripts in the local scope(using closure).

Even though it is not used in the current scope, it might be added as a matter of practice by the author

Answer (score 0):

You are using them all with the exception of "`_undefined`".

The construct:

```
function(argument,..) {
}("value",...)
```

The above construct is called an 'immediate function'. The function is defined without a name, and immediately executed with the arguments passed at the bottom, in your case `jQuery`, `this`, and `document`.

The function doesn't pollute the global space, since it doesn't even have a name, but its closure (everything defined between the functions curly braces), bakes in the values that you passed, so the code inside will have access to those variables even long after the function was executed.